Kotlin Serialization: MissingFieldException with Navigation Component and Default Values
I'm implementing navigation in a Jetpack Compose app using the Navigation Component and experiencing serialization issues. I have two related problems:

When I remove default values from my User data class, I get:

kotlin
kotlinx.serialization.MissingFieldException: Fields [email, displayName, authToken, voterId, candidateId, adminId] are required for type with serial name


When I remove the default User value from the Home destination, I get:

kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Companion' is not found.
Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.

Here's my relevant code:
@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
@Serializable
sealed interface Destination {
    // Other destinations...

    @Serializable
    data class Home(val user: User = User( // Absence of this is gives Missing Field exception
        email = "",
        displayName = "New User",
        authToken = "",
        voterId = 0,
        candidateId = 0,
        adminId = 0,
        profilePicture = null
    )) : Destination
}

@Serializable
data class User(
    val email: String = "",
    val displayName: String = "",
    val authToken: String = "",
    val voterId: Int? = null,
    val candidateId: Int? = null,
    val adminId: Int? = null,
    val profilePicture: String?
)

composable<Destination.Home>(
    typeMap = mapOf(typeOf<User>() to UserType)
) { backStackEntry ->
    val viewModel = koinViewModel<HomeViewModel>()
    val homeData: Destination.Home = backStackEntry.toRoute()
    eVoteViewModel.setUser(homeData.user)
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    HomeScreen(
        state = state,
        user = homeData.user,
        copyToClipboard = viewModel::copyToClipboard
    )
}

val UserType = object : NavType<User>(isNullableAllowed = false) {
    private val json = Json {
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        isLenient = true
        encodeDefaults = false
        explicitNulls = false
        prettyPrint = true
    }

    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): User {
        return json.decodeFromString(bundle.getString(key)!!)
    }

    override fun parseValue(value: String): User {
        return json.decodeFromString(Uri.decode(value))
    }

    override fun serializeAsValue(value: User): String {
        return Uri.encode(
            json.encodeToString(
                serializer = User.serializer(), value = value
            )
        )
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: User) {
        bundle.putString(key, json.encodeToString(value))
    }
}


To be clear, the code in question doesn't produce errors? Also, is startDestination = Destination.Home?

@JanItor yes, no compile time error. Yes startDestination = Destination.Home

You should set start destination as Destination.Home() if route is a data class. Same goes for navigate as well. navController.navigate(Destination.Home()) is how you navigate.

When you set startDestination to a data class like startDestination = Destination.Home, NavHost uses the overload that takes startDestination: Any and it takes the companion object of that data class as a route.
You can either create an instance of your data class:
startDestination = Destination.Home(user = someDefaultUser)

In this case you don't need a default value for user argument of Destination.Home.
Or pass it like a KClass:
startDestination = Destination.Home::class

In this case data class used as startDestination has to have default values for its properties, so NavHost can create an instance to serialize so you could retrieve it later via backStackEntry.toRoute().

but i want to pass dynamic data, this is my navigation logic
navController.navigate(Destination.Home(user)) {
popUpTo(Destination.AuthGraph) {
inclusive = true
}
}
this is my navigation logic. The value being used is the default user i passed in the User class

But you still can do it. You just need to provide some User for startDestination, either directly - startDestination = Destination.Home(defaultUser)  or with default value - data class Home(val user: User = defaultUser). As I understand you want to avoid default values, so first option is better for you. I've updated my answer to be less confusing, @androidDeweleper

this is my composable logic
composable<Destination.Home>() { backStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry ->
val homeData: Destination.Home = backStackEntry.toRoute()
HomeScreen(
voter = homeData.voter,
)
}
my navigaiton logic is
rootAction(RootAction.Navigate(RootDestination.Home(user)))
but in my HomeScreen i am getting the default user i passed in Destination.Home

I'm confused, what is RootDestination.Home and RootAction.Navigate? Do you have 2 different Home classes - Destination.Home and RootDestination.Home? It would help if you add more of your navigation to the question, with startDestination and all. @androidDeweleper

I found the flaw, i re wrote the code from scratch and there was a minor mistake, thank you for the help @JanItor
